# XCode 6 not recognizing second tableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

```
let cell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MessageTableViewCell
let cell2 = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MessageTableViewCell
```

The first cell is recognized fine. The second, is not. I have a storyboard with the proper identifiers set for each prototype cell. The (dynamic) tableView has both cells on it, which should be fine from what I understand. This is the exact error I receive:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell
>   with identifier Cell2 - must register a nib or a class for the
>   identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard

This would make perfect sense if the identifier for that second prototype cell wasn't "Cell2", however it is.

Here is the code in the entire function, notice how I am not even returning cell 2, simply dequeuing it:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell? {
    let cell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MessageTableViewCell
    let cell2 = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MessageTableViewCell

if UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation.isLandscape == true {
    cell.messageLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = cell.frame.size.width - 80
} else {
    cell.messageLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = cell.frame.size.width - 35
}

preferredWidth = cell.messageLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth

cell.messageLabel.text = friends[indexPath!.row]
cell.messageLabel.sizeToFit()
cell.messageLabel.setNeedsDisplay()

return cell
}
```

It crashes on that second line (inside the function).

Note: I am now using XCode 6 Beta 4.

Comment: Always use the latest beta which is as of now Beta 4.

Comment: I notice the same behaviour after making the modifications to the code that Beta 4 had shown.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because you are using an out of date beta version which you ca assume has less bugs than your current version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new nib, recreated the cell in there, and inserted this code, which all in combination solved the problem.

```
var nibName = UINib(nibName: "MainTableViewCell", bundle:nil)
self.tableView.registerNib(nibName, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SecondCell")
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this as well. Try this:

```
tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

Comment: I placed this in my viewDidLoad() func for "Cell2". The result is that now I am receiving an odd 'EXC_BREAKPOINT' message for Thread 1, its not in the console, its indicating a memory location. "Swift_dynamicCast" is in the header.

Comment: `let cell2 = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MessageTableViewCell` is still the line that causes this to happen, when removed the execution of the program occurs fine. +1 for suggestion, still not working however.

Comment: @user3871275 Make sure this line is placed after the table view has been allocated. Also, change `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2` to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell`  (notice the no 2, to match my answer's line)

Comment: Unfortunately I receive the same error. thanks anyway